# Change Prompt Error Message From Java Library

Tags: java, file-upload, zk, apache-commons-fileupload

currently I am working with zkoss, java, and maven. One of functionalities in my applications is uploading file.

When I did some testing regarding this functionality by uploading a very large file, I got a prompt error message, which said 
**"the request was rejected because its size (8356577) exceeds the configured maximum (1024000)"**

After I did several debugging, I found out that the prompt message is came from org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase, which is file from one of my maven dependencies.

Now, I would like to change the error message into something else. Is there any solution about how to do it? I prefer way without recompiling the library. Thanks a lot.

**-- UPDATED --**

Here is my web.xml. Did I do something wrong? Thanks again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Sistem Informasi Jabatan Fungsional</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      classpath:spring-ctx.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout> <!-- in minutes -->
  </session-config>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- For using session scoped bean -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>extention0</param-name>
      <param-value>/upload=uploader.UploadUtil</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- Must. Specifies URI of the update engine (DHtmlUpdateServlet). It must be the same as <url-pattern> 
      for the update engine. -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
      <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup><!-- MUST -->
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- Spring Security Filter Start Here -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <!-- Spring Security Filter End Here -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend from `org.zkoss.zk.au.http.AuUploader` and override the `handleError(Throwable)` method:

```
public class MyUploader extends AuUploader {
    @Override
    protected String handleError(Throwable ex)
    {
        return "mymessage";
    }        
}
```

Then you have to configure this extention in your web.xml:

In configuration of

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- extentions here -->
</servlet>
```

add:

```
<init-param>            
    <param-name>processor0</param-name>             
    <param-value>/upload=uploader.MyUploader</param-value>
</init-param>
```

May be `processor0` has to be changed to `extention0`, depending on your ZK version. `processor0` was testesd working with ZK 7.

The ZK documentation on this matter can be found [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Configuration%20Reference/web.xml/ZK%20AU%20Engine).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. First, what does "uploader" in the <init-param> refer to? And then, I have updated my questions and add my web.xml configuration. Can you please take a look whether I did something wrong with the config? I have tried your solution, but the handleError method is still not overrided. Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: You defined the servlet `DHtmlUpdateServlet` twice (and your own one is not mapped to a specific URL). You have to add the `<init-param>` to the existing servlet with the name `auEngine`. I added a link to the corresponding ZK-Specification in my Answer.